# deprecated 'sshKeys' metadata item | centos | latest guest environment already installed

Tags: centos, ssh, google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine

When login into GCP VM from browser i get a popup saying

> The VM guest environment is outdated and only supports the deprecated 'sshKeys' metadata item. Please follow the steps [here](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/images/guest-environment) to update.

**A:** I followed the instruction and updated the guest environment as mentioned [here](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/images/install-guest-environment#update-guest) and run following cmds

```
sudo yum makecache
sudo yum install google-compute-engine google-compute-engine-oslogin \
google-guest-agent google-osconfig-agent
```

**B:**
As a result, I now have the following packages

```
google-compute-engine-20210204.00-g1.el7.noarch 
google-compute-engine-oslogin-20210429.00-g1.el7.x86_64
google-guest-agent-20210223.01-g1.el7.x86_64 
google-osconfig-agent-20210429.3-g1.el7.x86_64
```

**C:** Restarted the VM and still getting the same msg of `The VM guest environment is outdated`

**What can be the issue?**.
**Note:** I am unable to use SSHMeta feature also, as I am trying SSHKey via meta for the first time on this vm. Also, this vm was created from an image which was more than two-year old

---

**PS:**
Have validated the environment as mentioned [here](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/images/install-guest-environment#wgei_services)

```
>>>sudo systemctl list-unit-files | grep google | grep enabled
google-accounts-manager.service               enabled 
google-address-manager.service                enabled 
google-clock-sync-manager.service             enabled 
google-guest-agent.service                    enabled 
google-osconfig-agent.service                 enabled 
google-shutdown-scripts.service               enabled 
google-startup-scripts.service                enabled 
google-oslogin-cache.timer                    enabled
```

```
serial port console also looks ok
```

Installed packages are

```
rpm -qa --queryformat '%{NAME}\n' \
> |grep -iE google\|gce | grep -iE \
> 'google|gce'
google-compute-daemon
google-compute-engine
google-cloud-sdk
google-compute-engine-oslogin
google-guest-agent
google-osconfig-agent
```

I do see logs that google-agent creates /home/user-configured-in-ssh-meta

But it does not add the key under authorizedkey file

Comment: Are you using an OS version that is no longer supported?

Comment: `cat /etc/centos-release` says `CentOS Linux release 7.9.2009 (Core)`
and [gcp documentation](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/images/install-guest-environment#os_support) says its supported

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Faced a similar issue while migrating an old VM.
I had to remove `google-compute-daemon.noarch` from old vm and update the guest environment.

Also make sure that you have installed followings:

```
gce-disk-expand.x86_64               1:20200716.00-g1.el7                @google-cloud-compute
google-cloud-sdk.noarch              293.0.0-1                           @google-cloud-sdk
google-compute-engine.noarch         1:20210204.00-g1.el7                @google-cloud-compute
google-compute-engine-oslogin.x86_64 1:20210429.00-g1.el7                @google-cloud-compute
google-guest-agent.x86_64            1:20210223.01-g1.el7                @google-cloud-compute
google-osconfig-agent.x86_64         1:20210429.3-g1.el7                 @google-cloud-compute
```